# Weird ,0 at top of .csv file while using Pandas with Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I want to print a dictionary into a csv file. Dictionary is containing a subject code as a key and a mark that one student got as a value.

Here is my .py code:

```
import pandas as pd

classes = dict()

print('Type STOP to end.\n')

while True:
    key = input('Subject ID: ')
    if key == 'STOP':
        break
    else:
        value = input('Mark: ')
        classes[key] = value

print(classes)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(classes, orient='index')
df.to_csv("student_report.csv")
```

Code prints the dict:

```
{'IT255': '10', 'IT335': '9', 'CS324': '10', 'CS225': '7'}
```

Here is csv file:

```
,0
IT255,10
IT335,9
CS324,10
CS225,7
```

I don't know what is causing the ,0 at the top. Any help?

UPDATE

Printing the data frame brings this:

```
        0
IT255  10
IT335   9
CS324  10
CS225   7
```

Comment: Print the dataframe as well. What do you see?

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion

Comment: That's good, but I mostly meant it as something for you to think about: what do _you_ see happening?

Comment: Try to open the csv file using an editor and manually check for the first line. Then delete any white space characters if they exist. Then try to run your code again. make sure the following ```IT255  10
``` is written in the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas insists that each column have a title, and it wants to write those column names as the CSV header.  Since you didn't provide any column names in your import, pandas assigns names to the columns.  The first column is an index, which doesn't need a name.  The other columns are assigned names starting with 0.  You can supply your own column names with the `header` parameter to `to_csv`, or pass `header=False` to suppress them.

As a side note, if this is ALL you are using `pandas` for, it would be MUCH more efficient to use the Python `csv` module.  `pandas` is a very large module that can take multiple second to load.  If you don't need its fancy capabilities, just use `csv`.

Comment: adding header = False to to_csv() worked. Thank you alot